# How to get asymptotic solution for vector iteration process as $f^{n+1}=B G B^T f^{n}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, fixed-point-theorems

Where $B$ is $M\times N$ matrix, $G$ is $N \times N$ orthonormal matrix, and $B^T$ is the transpose of $B$. For $N=1$, it is easy to see the asymptotic solution is the eigenvector of $B B^T$. But for $N>1$, I would like to know any simple relation to the matrix $B B^T$. Thanks.

Comment: Why would this even converge in some sense?

Comment: This comes from a physical model. I am not coming from a math field, and not sure to what to say about the structure of $B$ and $G$. But I know the model makes sense physically. Increasing $N$ is something like increasing grid resolution.  Is there any possible simple solution to this problem with all "good" assumptions on $B$ and $G$?

Comment: Would the eigendecomposition of $BGB^T$ (as a single matrix) be reasonably accessible? The evolution of this system could be described quite simply in terms of those eigenvalues and eigenvectors.

Comment: @Kajelad Thanks for your suggestion. That is something I am trying to find. In fact, the full problem is as $B (\frac{G_1}{\lambda_1} + \frac{G_2}{\lambda_2} + \cdots) B^T$. The middle part comes from  a matrix spectral decomposition like $\lambda_1 G_1+\lambda_2 G_2+\cdots$. $G$ is symmetric. I just don't know how to get the decomposition for the whole part. Any clue?